# Configuring php to work with httpd, Autostarting mysqld and apachectl

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, redhat, httpd

I am very new to Linux Environment.
But for my client I've designed the website which uses php and mysql.
Now I want to install the site on his RHEL 5.0 server. He already have httpd installed on it.

So My problem now is:
I've installed apachectl to be able to listen php function calls in :

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl
```

and php in:

```
/usr/local/php
```

with mysqld:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Now to start the website I use:

```
 service httpd stop
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
```

And it works fine.
But My client want no change in his server setup. 
He wants

- to run both php and mysql using only httpd **No apachectl** and also
- if apachectl is to be used then he want to start it automatically  when OS boots up after a power failure
- Is it possible to configure php and mysql to work with httpd(No apachectl) ?

I know how to do this in windows OS(using control panel) but can anyone help me in Linux?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Your client wants an ancient version of Linux and wants you to replace all the system packages instead of just using something more up-to-date to begin with? Run away.

Comment: @Michael_Hampton♦ I really want to run away :) :D. But I can't. Can you help me in this.

Comment: Will editing `httpd.conf` work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of confused with your question, correct me if I'm wrong, but if you only want httpd and mysql to start at boot you need to look at xinetd.

To get what you want should be something like this:

```
/usr/sbin/update-rc.d [service-name] defaults
```

check [this link](http://www.linuxmail.info/how-to-start-stop-services-centos-6/) for further information